# Who is Lillith?

Tags: genesis

The character Lilith, while not mentioned in the Bible, turns up in Christian mythology as Adam’s first wife. (She’s mentioned, for example, in CS Lewis’ *Chronicles of Narnia*.) Where does this myth originate? And does any major Christian denomination teach the Lilith story as true?

Comment: See also: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/10/68

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lillith was a figure in Jewish legend.
There's a good answer to your question here: http://jewishchristianlit.com/Topics/Lilith/

Here's an excerpt:

> While it is true that there was a rabbinic tradition that Adam briefly
>   had another wife before the creation of Eve (Genesis Rabbah), there is
>   a great deal of doubt as to whether Lilith had any connection at all
>   to this first wife of Adam story prior the publication of the
>   Alphabet. The satirical nature of the Alphabet casts further doubt on
>   the authenticity of this Lilith connection. But whatever its origins,
>   the connection between Lilith and the first Eve seems to have struck a
>   chord with Jewish folk imagination and it is now an inexorable part of
>   those traditions.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the translation, Lilith *does* appear in the Bible at Isaiah 34:14. In that verse, there's a word לִּילִית which is transliterated to lilit and translated to a variety of different things including Lilith, Lamia, and screech owl.

Notably, the New American Bible—used prominently by us American Roman Catholics—translates Isaiah 34:14 as:

> Wildcats shall meet with desert beasts, satyrs shall call to one another; There shall the **lilith** repose, and find for herself a place to rest.

It's understood by the context that lilith is some kind of demon.

However, the myth of Lilith being Adam's first wife dates from the Medieval period, specifically a story within the second alphabet of of Jesus ben Sirach. Wikipedia [has the full textual mention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_of_Ben_Sira#Lilith) of Lilith from the Alphabet, but it's not a Christian story: it's Jewish in origin.

Because it dates from the Medieval period, no mainstream Christian denomination teaches it as even remotely true or divinely inspired.