# What place does Lilith have in Christianity? 

Tags: bible, biblical-basis, old-testament, adam-and-eve

There was a show on the History channel stating that some scholars believe Adam and Eve were alive with a third human, Lilith. Lilith disobeyed Adam and Eve, so God sent her to live on earth as a demon.

Is this just Jewish mythology or should it be considered part of the religion?

What place does Lilith have in Christianity? Is she part of the devil, an evil angel, is she relevant today?

How should a Christian view her? For example, Adam and Eve directly effect each of our lives right now, since eating from the tree of knowledge...is there something analogous to this with Lilith?

http://www.bitterwaters.com/Lilith_in_Bible.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith#In_the_Bible

Thank You.

Comment: Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3746/who-is-lillith

Comment: Also related: [What word best captures the spirit of לִּילִית in Isaiah 34:14?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/10/68)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Christianity is based on the Bible.  One of the tenets of Protestantism is "sola scriptura" (Scripture alone).  Lilith is not mentioned in the Bible, and thus has no relevance to Christianity.

Some parts of Christianity also consider tradition as well as the Bible, but that doesn't sound like Christian tradition either.

Christians can view non-biblical ideas as myths, history, or whatever, as seems appropriate.

Comment: cool, I guess that opens the debate as some think she is mentioned...o well, thanks.

Comment: You can use biblegateway.com to search for words or phrases.  She's not mentioned by name in the NIV, nor do I recall seeing the name in various versions I have read.

Comment: You've added references.  The wikipedia article mentioned a hapax, which is most appropriately not used for Christian practice (although many do anyway).  The other is creative interpretation, and if we want to do that, we can come up with all sorts of beliefs.  Many people do that too.  Does that make it Christian?  That's a much bigger question.

Comment: There was no Christianity between the life of Jesus and the compilation of the current form of the bible?

Answer (score 2):

Lilit, from the Hebrew לִילִית, is popularized by Jewish *midrashim*. I do not believe it (or she) has ever had a place in Christianity.

An excerpt from Gesenius' lexicon on the OT:

[image]

(The comments in brackets are redactions made by S. P. Tregelles when he translated Gesenius' lexicon into English.)

The word occurs once in Isa. 34:14 where it is translated as "screech owl" by the A.V.