# Did God create other people besides Adam and Eve?

Tags: creation, adam-and-eve, cain

After Cain killed Abel, he was cast away and said "whoever finds me will kill me", there he took a wife.

I think this indicates there were other people on the face of the earth created by God, but are there any other explanations?

The reason I ask this is that Adam and Eve are supposedly the couple that gave birth to all humanity, which I think is genetically impossible.

Comment: [Lillith](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3746/214). ;)

Comment: "Literal" and "non-literal" Christian views will disagree on this, so this is a Truth question that will lead to a voting contest.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/why-is-cain-afraid-when-he-is-driven-away-from-god

Comment: Please narrow this to a subset of Christian views on the subject. As Alypius points out there is a wide range of potential interpretations here. Please do some research to determine which potential reading you want more information or clarification on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Adam named his wife Eve, because she would become the mother of all the living." Genesis 3:20 (NIV). 
So according to Genesis Eve was the mother of all living, so that means there were no other directly created people. Also Romans 5:12 "Therefore, just as sin entered the world through one man, and death through sin, and in this way death came to all people, because all sinned." 
If there were more directly created people, original sin would mean nothing because it would not have been passed on, there would have been lines where Adams sin would not have "infected" his none-offspring.

The assertion that this is genetically impossible is certainly not a scientific one for whatever passes for "science" in your mind, the consensus even among evolutionist atheists has been for quite some time that modern humans had a single matriarchal ancestor.
Anyone who claims it's science to say two people with the proper genetic code can't create the diversity we have today doesn't understand basic genetics. (And neither did Darwin, he was a botanist NOT an educated biologist).

Comment: I guess that Genesis 3:20 clears that up. Also Romans. Really nice to have these Bible verses. Exactly what I was looking for. Totaly forgot about them. Thanks.

Comment: "[W]hatever passes for 'science' in your mind[.]" And you wonder why these godless, "evolutionary [A]theists" deem the religious uneducated?
Genetic diversity needs only **one** thing to occur- ***genetic diversity***. Adam and Eve share the same genetic code (Eve being made out of Adam's rib), therefore making it impossible for variation to be present.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET I asked mainly hoping for the Biblical approach on whether or not where other people created. On the genetic side, I found valid explanations elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Bible, God created no other people besides Adam and Eve.  Adam was created from the dust of the earth, while Eve was created from Adam (perhaps his rib).

Genesis 5 indicates that Adam and Eve had quite a few children.  We have names for Cain, Abel, Seth, other sons (plural) and daughters (plural).  So, at a minimum, they had seven children.  If we assume that the birthrate for women is just equal to that of men, then Eve may well have had five daughters, pushing the total to ten.  The earth at that time was very fruitful, and people lived a very long time, so she may well have had more than that.

Genetically speaking, it is not impossible at all that one couple could give birth to all humanity.  Just because one scientist asserts something to be true does not make it so.

See [this article](http://www.answersingenesis.org/get-answers/features/adam-eve-skin-tones-one-race) regarding skin tones and [this article](http://www.icr.org/article/6314/) regarding a challenge to that claim altogether.

Comment: I would not want to defend the position that God created no other people besides Adam and Eve.  In addition to the evidence cited in the question, you do have science against you on this one.

Comment: @rmayer06 There was no scientific evidence cited in the question--only an assertion.  My answer does cite scientific articles, so I actually have science with me on this one.  In reality, there are scientific assertions on both sides.

Comment: My point wasn't that there is no "evidence" on both sides. My point is that the view of exactly *how* god created them is simplistic and in contrast to what is commonly accepted as scientific fact. Therefore, if your evangelization effort requires someone to ultimately accept this series of events as fact, you will have an unnecessary (and irrelevant) stumbling block to the faith.

Answer (score 4):

Let me bring up some unauthentic book.

The  [Book of Adam and Eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Adam_and_Eve) gives a good explanation to this confusion. The first son, Cain was born along with his twin sister Luluwa. The second son, Abel also had a twin sister Aklia. After Cain murdered Abel, **Cain married his twin sister Luluwa**.

As we know, the Bible rarely mentions the name of women, their is no doubt that those first daughters of Adam and Eve were also not mentioned in the Bible. The writer, probably Moses might have assume that there was no strong reason to mention the names of the first daughters and might even did not think that the readers like us will later come up with this kind of questions.

When Cain said `"whoever finds me will kill me"`, it does not necessarily mean that there were already other people on earth. Remember that those days the lifespan of human was above 900 years and less than 1000 years. Cain simply meant that the people who will born later will want to kill him because he is a murderer. And we know very well that **900 years is enough for a civilization to rise**. Although Cain did not know how long he will live, he also did not know when he will die. There was no one yet who saw how a man will die of old age. Cain would surely think that he will at least live for a long time because death by old age was not yet known to them.

Comment: Well, we know that [it took China 1000 years to reach a level of basic civilization](http://www.angelfire.com/ca2/kushana/Civilization.html), making me question your thesis.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET "Civilization" is a controversial term indeed. The intention is only to highlight the possibility of many nations coming out of just a single couple.